# Is there a way to change the y axis on Gnuplot so that my image graphs from hour 16 to hour 15 instead of 0 to 24?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm sorry if this has already been asked, I couldn't find it anywhere, but I have an image plot on gnuplot of a three-columned data file for a y range [0:24] and I can't figure out how to use gnuplot to rearrange the image graph so my y axis runs from 16:24 and then 0:16 (in that order and on the same axis). The command I've been using is "plot [] [0:24] '/Users/eleanor/PycharmProjects/attempt2.gray' u 1:2:3 w image" but I don't know what command to use so that hour 16 is at the very bottom instead of 0, and then when y reaches 23:59 y goes to 0 next and then continues increasing up to 15:59 at the very top of the axis. I'm not sure if that makes sense or not, and I've already tried changing the y range to [16:15] and that did nothing except give me an error lol. Any tips would be very much appreciated! :)

a piece of the file im using is below (with the first column being the day of year, the second being the time in decimal hours, and the third being the data):

```
20  0.0    7.327484247409568
20  0.002777777777777778    8.304658863945411
20  0.005555555555555556    11.641408500506405
20  0.008333333333333333    6.543382279013497
20  0.011111111111111112    13.922090817182697
20  0.013888888888888888    10.696406455987988
20  0.016666666666666666    12.537636516165243
20  0.019444444444444445    11.816216763447612
20  0.022222222222222223    8.914413125514413
20  0.025   5.8225423124691496
20  0.027777777777777776    10.896730484548698
20  0.030555555555555555    9.097140108173859
```

Comment: Can you please share a few lines of the file so we know what format the time uses etc.?

Comment: yes of course I'm sorry: 20 0.0 7.3274842474095685
20 0.002777777777777778 8.304658863945411
20 0.005555555555555556 11.641408500506405
20 0.008333333333333333 6.543382279013497
20 0.011111111111111112 13.922090817182697
20 0.013888888888888888 10.696406455987988 (so it goes from 0 to 366 days in the first column, these rows are all from january 20th, and for each day it goes from 0 to 24 in decimal time in the second column)

Comment: okay for some reason the formatting is messed up now and the columns are gone. I apologize for my technological incompetence 

Comment: Update the question instead of commenting. Use code formatting for the data.

Comment: Okay I think I fixed it! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

As currently implemented, `with image` treats the entire block of data as a single entity.  You can't chop it up into pieces within a single `plot` command.  However if your data is dense enough, it may be that you can approximate the same effect by plotting each pixel as a colored square:

```
  set xrange [*:*] noextend
  set yrange [0:24]
  plot 'datafile' using 1:(($2>16.)? ($2-16.) : ($2+8.)):3 with points pt 5 lc palette
```

I strongly recommend *not* making the range limits part of the plot command. Set them beforehand using `set xrange` and `set yrange`.

If necessary, you can adjust the size of the individual square "pixels" by using `set pointsize P` where P is a scale factor. It probably looks best if you make the points just large enough (or small enough) to touch each other. I think the default ones in the image I show are too large.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the boxxyerror plotting style instead of the image plotting style. Well, here's what the help for boxxyerror says

```
gnuplot> ? boxxyerror
 The `boxxyerror` plot style is only relevant to 2D data plotting.
 It is similar to the `xyerrorbars` style except that it draws rectangular areas
 rather than crosses.  It uses either 4 or 6 basic columns of input data.
 Additional input columns may be used to provide information such as
 variable line or fill color (see `rgbcolor variable`).
      4 columns:  x  y  xdelta  ydelta
      6 columns:  x  y  xlow  xhigh  ylow  yhigh

 ....
```

If you adopt the four-column plotting style above, you must specify xdelta and ydelta in addition to x and y to specify the rectangle. The xdelta and ydelta should be the half-width and half-height of each pixel. From your data, let's say xdelta is half of 1 and ydelta is half of 0.002777777777777778 hours.

Our final script will look like this.
In this script, the second column of "using" is the same as Ethan's answer.

```
dx = 1.0/2.0
dy = 0.002777777777777778/2.0

set xrange [-1:32]  
set yrange [0:24]   
set ytics ("16" 0, "20" 4, "0" 8, "4" 12, "8" 16, "12" 20, "16" 24)

set palette defined (0 "green", 0.5 "yellow", 1 "red")

unset key

plot "datafile" using 1:($2>16?($2-16):($2+8)):(dx):(dy):3 \
                with boxxy palette
```

[image]